# listview printing PrintPage(s)

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, graphics, printing

I am making a quiz program right now, but I really need some help about printing items from listview in vb.net.  I can display the items successfully in print preview but my problem is how do I move into the next page if the current page is near to the end of paper(A4)? And also how do I make it auto adjust so that if the question/answer is too long, it will wrap the text to the next line. I am new to this thing that's why I don't have any idea what should I do next. Please help. So far, this is my code. Many thanks..

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage 

        Dim font1 As New Font("Verdana", 11, FontStyle.Regular)
        Dim ctr As Integer = 0
        Dim nextline As Integer = 0

        Do
            e.Graphics.DrawString(ctr + 1 & ": " & ListView1.Items(ctr).SubItems(3).Text, 
                    font1, Brushes.Black, 100, 30 + nextline)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("A: " & ListView1.Items(ctr).SubItems(4).Text, 
                    font1, Brushes.Black, 100, 60 + nextline)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("B: " & ListView1.Items(ctr).SubItems(5).Text, 
                    font1, Brushes.Black, 100, 90 + nextline)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("C: " & ListView1.Items(ctr).SubItems(6).Text, 
                    font1, Brushes.Black, 100, 120 + nextline)
            e.Graphics.DrawString("D: " & ListView1.Items(ctr).SubItems(7).Text, 
                    font1, Brushes.Black, 100, 150 + nextline)

            nextline = nextline + 200

            ctr = ctr + 1
        Loop Until ctr = ListView1.Items.Count

End Sub
```

Comment: rather that looping on `ListView1.Items.Count` you need to calculate how many will fit on a page given the font and such. When you get to the end of THAT loop, set `e.HasMorePages` to True or False to continue on the next page.  See MSDN for a [good example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: ok thanks. so how about wrapping the text? Because if the question is too long, it wont go to the next line

Comment: One of the DrawString overloads allows you specify a Rectangle to constrain the text.  When it wraps you have to adjust the line/Y position accordingly....OR you can set a format flag to truncate and use ellipses (...)

Comment: im sorry but i am getting confuse because im not familiar in printing using graphics.. How do I make that? can you give some example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3314898/1070452